# Implementing a 'function-calling function'

Tags: function, functional-programming, python

I would like to write a bit of code that calls a function specified by a given argument.  EG:

```
def caller(func):
    return func()
```

However what I would also like to do is specify optional arguments to the 'caller' function so that 'caller' calls 'func' with the arguments specified (if any).

```
def caller(func, args):
# calls func with the arguments specified in args
```

Is there a simple, pythonic way to do this?

Comment: This is scarily meta.  Are you sure you're not over-generalizing something?

Comment: @Greg: Thanks for your concern. :)  This isn't for production code.  I'm going to be testing something for my school work and I thought "There has to be a way to do that in python."

So I asked. :)

Comment: Hey! This is totally normal! I use this for production code all the time. Usecase: protocol implementation: dictionary of {tokens:functions} then match against tokens, call function. If the token is an explicit state, you have a state machine. Python is _made_ for this! Not scarily meta at all. Wish I could downvote your comment Greg :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by using [arbitrary argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
>>> def caller(func, *args, **kwargs):
...     return func(*args, **kwargs)
...
>>> def hello(a, b, c):
...     print a, b, c
...
>>> caller(hello, 1, b=5, c=7)
1 5 7
```

Not sure *why* you feel the need to do it, though.

Answer (score 7):

This already exists as the [apply](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply) function, though it is considered obsolete due to the new *args and **kwargs syntax.

```
>>> def foo(a,b,c): print a,b,c
>>> apply(foo, (1,2,3))
1 2 3
>>> apply(foo, (1,2), {'c':3})   # also accepts keyword args
```

However, the * and ** syntax is generally a better solution.  The above is equivalent to:

```
>>> foo(*(1,2), **{'c':3})
```